# how to deploy SSIS package in vitual machine(azure) from local machine?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I have created SSIS package and I can able to deploy in my local server as well using SQL Server 2012. but when I try to deploy the package in virtual machine (azure) server I am getting the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Is there any way to do the deployment in virtual machine server?

Comment: I've always deployed manually to our virtual machines. Not sure if it's possible

Comment: ok. can you give me the brief idea about how to deploy manually..

Comment: Added to a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way is to deploy the packages manually. By this I mean copying and pasting to a shared folder on the server. Make sure connection managers are set up to use [environment variables](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-environmental-variable1731/) so that you can deploy between environments without having to change configuration settings